# Change timezone used by Kendo UI for jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Our system supports more than the local timezone. For example I am in Vancouver looking at data for Perth Australia. It is the 16th in Vancouver, but the 17th in Perth, so the Kendo calendar (date picker) is highlighting the 16th as "today". Is there some way to set the current day as the 17th (in this example).

Answer (score 0):

The timezones option is not set by default and, therefore, the event dates will be created based on the current client timezone offset. Setting the Scheduler timezone will force the widget to show the same start and end times regardless of the user's timezone.

You just have to add **timezone: "Etc/UTC"** to your scheduler configuration.
[here is a sample](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/timezone)

[List of timezones codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Thanks, but that's a Scheduler; I am using a calendar/date picker. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker